Firebase DOMException when the sign up and sign in method is called
When the userCredential object is called in sign in or account creation methods an DOMexception is thrown
The user is successfully created, but cannot be used due to an exception

loginForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {

  e.preventDefault();

  

  const email = loginForm['login-email'].value;

  const password = loginForm['login-password'].value;

  

  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)

  .then((userCredential) => {

    // Signed in 

    const user = userCredential.user; //DOMException

  });

})

DOMException
I tried to recreate the project and did not find information on the Internet

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

I don't see how the code you have now could ever cause a DOMException, especially not the line you have commented as such.  Please be sure that you have the correct line of code.
